# Round Up SVG Path

Tags: svg, bezier

I am new to drawing vectors using svg and I am trying to create a custom tab bar for my app's navigations. I want it to look something like this:

[image: example]

I was able to create something similar:

[image]

And the svg code looks like this:

```
  const width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
  const firstStop = width / 2 - 30;
  const secondStop = width / 2 + 28;

        <Path
          d={`
          M 0,0 
          H ${firstStop - 30} 
          Q ${firstStop},0
          ${firstStop},0
          ${firstStop},35 
          ${firstStop + 30},35 
          ${secondStop},35 
          ${secondStop},0
          ${secondStop},0 
          ${secondStop + 30},0 
          H ${width} 
          V 70 
          H 0 
          Z`}
          fill={colors.accent}
          fillRule='nonzero'
        />
```

But, as you can see, I created it with sharp edges. I wanted to achieve the smoother edge for the "cutout". How can I create such curve in this case? I think i don't quite grasp the `Q` path in this case.

Comment: By firing up [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), or [Illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/ca/products/illustrator.html), or any other of a number of vector drawing programs, drawing the curve you want, and then exporting to SVG, then copying the path from that.

Comment: oh that is a good idea, thank you!! i was drawing and calculating it on a sheet of paper :)

Comment: If its just a single d-path, paste it in: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#

Comment: Good starting point would be `m 0 4 h 5 c 2 0 1 2 3 2 c 2 0 1 -2 3 -2 h 5 v 5 h -16 z` - try to keep curve control lines horizontal or vertical.

Comment: @Ruskin only give that advice if you can also explain why that's important to do (and there's good reasons for it in certain contexts, but absolutely not all contexts, so it's become one of those things that folks keep repeating, without knowing why they're repeating it, in contexts where it doesn't matter =)